# Variable not assigning after network call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

My variavle `d` is returning `nil`

```
var d: Int!

Alamofire.request(mapsUrl).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        let jsonObject = JSON(response.result.value)
        let value = jsonObject["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"].int

        var converted = 0
        if value! <= 5000{
            converted = (value! / 1000) * 80
        }else{
            converted = (value! / 1000) * 65
        }
        if converted < 400{
            converted = 400
        }else if converted == 0{
            converted = 400
        }
        d = converted
    })
print(d)
```

But `d` is returning nil

Comment: Please have a look at the Alamofire README which explicitly states that all requests are handled *asynchronously.*

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to `print(d)` outside of the completion block, that statement will be executed before your network request is completed. Try putting that inside the completion block:

```
Alamofire.request(mapsUrl).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
    let jsonObject = JSON(response.result.value)
    let value = jsonObject["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"].int

    var converted = 0
    if value! <= 5000{
        converted = (value! / 1000) * 80
    }else{
        converted = (value! / 1000) * 65
    }
    if converted < 400{
        converted = 400
    }else if converted == 0{
        converted = 400
    }
    d = converted
    print(d)
})
```

Comment: I want to return `d` in the function

Comment: See @Martin R's comment. I suggest you read up on asynchronous programming